# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, poo, fetch

Me da ese error al intentar recuperar de la base de datos unos registros.

query:

```
public function GetClientes(){
    $execquery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES");
    $result = $execquery->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $result;}
```

tratado de datos:

```
 $resultclientes = $obj->GetClientes();
 foreach ($resultalbaranes as $row){
    $idcliente = $row['fkcliente'];
    $nombrecliente = $row['nombrecliente'];
    $emailcliente = $row['email1'];
}
```

Pues bien, la cuestión es que me funciona, pero en DevTools, al entrar a la llamada a ese archivo, no puedo ver nada, ya que al darme ese Fatal error no me muestra nada más.

A parte de que quiero ver otras cosas del fichero, como echos, me gustaría que me explicarais porque da ese error ya que, lo que yo entiendo por encima encima, es que $execquery contiene un boolean, y al usar fetch_all, como que no le gusta ese tipo de datos (???)

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Sr_McLister

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es originado en el statment anterior, `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES");`, que devuelve `false`. Luego no tiene sentido llamar la función `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` de `false`.

En todo caso es necesario verificar el que el resultado no sea `false` antes de llamar la función como se muestra en los ejemplos de la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php):

```
    if ($execquery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES")) {
        $result = $execquery->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

De igual manera se debe haber verificado previamente que la conexión `$obj->db` exista y haya sido exitosa.

Por último, hay que tener cuidado al usar `SELECT *` en producción como se explica ene esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085208/why-shouldnt-we-use-select-in-a-mysql-query-on-a-production-server).

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli)